# QTip with Fullcalendar on eventMouseover

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar, qtip2

this is the right way for a qtip? Don't work for me.

```
eventMouseover: (event, jsEvent, view ) ->
  $(this).qtip
    content:
      text: event.description
    ready: true
    style:
      classes: "custom-class" # Custom class method or...
```

We can see the js.coffee -> http://pastebin.com/mNxJmZJe

I use the qTip2 v2.2.0 and jQuery v1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

Based on FullCalendar documentation qtip is being used the following way:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            employee: 'name'
        }
        // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.employee
        });
    }
});
```

Here's a link to the documentation regarding qtip: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have this error ( Uncaught TypeError: Property 'employee' of object #<Object> is not a function ). See here the code -> http://pastebin.com/Xfa2tnsd

Comment: You should include employee in the event:

Comment: I edited my answer above to reflect your event.employee